# How can I copy XML attributes using Minidom?

Tags: python, xml

I'm manipulating an XML document using Minidom in Python, and trying to create several similar copies of the same element. In order to do so, I was hoping to iterate over the attributes of the original, setting them in the clone each time. Is this the best way to do this?

So my implementation as it stands is:

```
attributes = original.attributes
for ii in range(attributes.length):
    item = attributes.item(ii)
    clone.setAttribute(item.name, item.value)
```

My problem with this is that it's clunky - surely there's an iterable that I can use to get all the attributes from a Minidom element? `original.attributes` in the snippet above returns a `NamedNodeMap` object, and in order to get to the attributes you have to do like above, which doesn't seem pythonic at all...

Answer (score 0):

In the end I settled for a slightly more elegant solution:

`for key, val in original.attributes.items():
    clone.setAttribute(key, val)`